# Are there any angularJS modules for IP subnet calculation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, ip

I have question about IP subnet calculation in angularJS.

I searched the internet for directive or any other easy to implement in AngularJS  module that will provide me easy calculation of network,router,IP address from, IP address to,broadcast, network mask. The only thing that I found are libraries posted in npm like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipv4-calculator

In npm libraries there is a problem that they are using require.js and in my project I'm not allowed to use it.

Have anyone found something similar but working directly with AngularJS?

Comment: Why not just add functions and add it to the directive?  example JS to add to calculate a few things:  http://www.thaemlitz.com/john/javascript-ip-subnet-calculator.html

Comment: You are right. I have to search pure JS code of calculation Subnet and simply add it to own directives. I wasn't thinking about it this way. So the problem with requre.js is solved and if there are no directives created by someone else I'll have to write my own. Thanks ;)